# Error: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I have the below data.

```
df3[~df3['total_sqft'].apply(is_float)].head(10)
```

[image: Click this link for the Data]

In the above data i've values like **3067 - 8156** in **total_sqft** column and I'm trying to find **average of min and max value in the range** by using the below code but it is throwing me an error.

```
def convert_sqft_to_num(x):
    tokens = x.split('-')
    if len(tokens) == 2:
        return (float(tokens[0])+float(tokens[1]))/2
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return None


df4 = df3.copy()
df4.total_sqft = df4.total_sqft.apply(convert_sqft_to_num)
df4 = df4[df4.total_sqft.notnull()]
df4.head(2)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Can some one help me to correct the code please.

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: Your function is expected to work on string, but you feed an integer and it fails on first statement x.split('-')

Comment: Looks like the data in your `total_sqft` column doesn't all follow the same format.  If an entry is not in the `x - y` format, then your assumptions about the result of the split operation won't be correct.

Comment: Maybe try make a fully reproducible example where you create a dataframe in code - that should allow you to spot the problem

Comment: @Evgeny thanks for that, I tried converting the ```total_sqft``` to ```int``` and is working fine now.